# How to set the nuxt assets url after build

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, nuxt.js, subdirectory

Hello every i am having issue after deploying the nuxt app to subdirectory, now the assets are not found here is the screen shot, the red border represent the assets url
[image]

Comment: Can you please give us the code of your component and also the structure of your file?

Comment: Hi, can you please provide more info, as asked above?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the image in the **assets** folder, then you can load your image with:

```html
<img src="~/assets/my_image.jpg" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but the images are already in assets folder but after running the npm run build then the files in dist folder does not work on server